# Cannot serialize JavaScript function

Tags: java, xpages, ssjs

I'm trying to change the page persistence in our XPages application, intending to move from "Keep pages in memory" to "Keep only the current page in memory". And of course I get run-time errors telling me that XPages cannot serialize a JavaScript function. But which function? The stack trace only shows the standard Java error stuff, but nothing about which variable or function cannot be serialized?

I had similar issues before, and it always cost me a lot of time to dig deep in the code and solve the problem. It takes ages... and I've really had it by now.

Is there a clever way to find out which function cannot be serialized??

**UPDATE**

What OpenLog Logger comes up with:

```
Client Version
Release 9.0.1FP3
January  12, 2015
Database    aalto803.nsf
Agent   /aASK.xsp
Method  class java.lang.StackTraceElement.writeValue
Error Num   -
Error Line  364
Error Msg   Impossible de sérialiser une fonction JavaScript
Language    Java

Stack Trace
java.io.IOException: Impossible de sérialiser une fonction JavaScript
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSValue.writeValue(FBSValue.java:364)
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSDefaultObject.writeExternal(FBSDefaultObject.java:746)
at com.ibm.jscript.std.ObjectObject.writeExternal(ObjectObject.java:106)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1462)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:942)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1020)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1502)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared(ObjectOutputStream.java:413)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectOutputStream.writeObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:438)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectOutputStream.writeObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:417)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectOutputStream.writeObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:417)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectOutputStream.writeObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:417)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectOutputStream.writeObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:417)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager.saveSerializedView(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:294)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager.doSaveSerializedView(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:269)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.FileStateManager.doSaveSerializedView(FileStateManager.java:290)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.FileStateManager.doSaveSerializedView(FileStateManager.java:270)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractStateManager.saveSerializedView(AbstractStateManager.java:114)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.StateManagerImpl.saveSerializedView(StateManagerImpl.java:152)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._saveViewState(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:455)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.saveViewState(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:449)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:324)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
```

Comment: Java in Domino XPages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recent discovery of mine answers this question too IMHO, see [XPages: how to put a Java Date value in an ObjectObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475816/xpages-how-to-put-a-java-date-value-in-an-objectobject/60846676#60846676) . A few years back, I started with moving my code from SSJS to Java, and I had some (better: a lot of) trouble with the ObjectObject and ArrayObject classes, mostly with the rather ugly way values have to be converted using a class called FBSUtility.

My main issue was with the fact that I couldn't manage to store a Date in an ObjectObject object. In a later stage, I was happy to have found a call with a JSContext parameter, `FBSUtility.wrap(jsContext, someDate)`, which permits storing a Date value. Call me clueless, about what the JSContext actually does here (which I am), but I thought that was the end to it.

Recently, in order to test our application, I changed the Persistence Mode, from a few pages in memory to everything on disk, hence forcing the serialization of all objects. I found out that a specific element of my application no longer worked, always stopping on a Serialization error. Further tests proved that there were no errors when I removed all Date values from the OO object.

Earlier, I had already adopted JsonJavaObject and JsonJavaArray classes for some other parts of the application (yeah I know, messy coding, big application, never time to do things right, 50 Mb template db, etc.). I rewrote the code to remove all use of the classes JSContext, FBSUtility, ObjectObject and ArrayObject, to replace them with the JsonJava classes, and there's no longer the dreaded message that a JS function cannot be serialized.

So, what I learned is: if your Persistence Mode is set to `Keep pages on Disk` or `Keep only the current page in memory`, try avoid ObjectObject objects and **never** use FBSUtility in combination with JSContext.

Answer (score 0):

XPages OpenLog Logger not only catches uncaught exceptions (it sounds like this is one of those), but also catches which component triggered the problem. It needs an error XPage in the application (otherwise after the error occurs there is no Render Response phase run, from which XPages OpenLog Logger retrieves the details). That might help you track it down.

Otherwise, check what functions you're storing in viewScope etc. That might help you narrow things down. SSJS is not really designed for object orientated programming, which I think is where issues arise when storing functions in scope.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is not so much WHICH function can't be serialized, its that NONE of your functions can be serialized. OR if you want to get very technical, none can be expected to persist in any way reliably. SSJS is not meant to be serialized. In this blog post here: http://xomino.com/2014/03/26/why-learning-javascript-is-more-critical-to-xpage-developers-than-java/ there is a good discussion in the comments about why and where serialization is toxic, specifically with SSJS (you can sort of disregard the actual discussion surrounding the blog post of java vs JavaScript - just concentrate on the bits concerning serialization).

Comment: I know they cannot be serialized. It's just that I have to find the bugger, in a few thousand lines of code. Some was developed over 3 years ago, and sifting through them manually isn't one of my favourite pastimes. Is there an isSerializable method or so? It must be something in a viewScope variable, but which one? The trace says it's serializing a HashMap, that much I understand, but is there nothing that tells me which value is "wrong" ?