# XPages: how to put a Java Date value in an ObjectObject

Tags: java, xpages

```
ObjectObject oo= new ObjectObject();
oo.put("name", FBSUtility.wrap("Wiley E."));
oo.put("DoB", new Date());  // <-- no can do
```

How can I put a Java Date in an ObjectObject? There is no .wrap method for a Date value. It must be possible somehow, for I can get one out using

```
Date d= oo.get("DoB").dateValue();
```

but how to put one in?? Thanks!!

***UPDATE***

This is what I used a long time:

```
JSContext jsContext = JavaScriptUtil.getJSContext();
ObjectObject oo = new ObjectObject();
oo.put("due", FBSUtility.wrap(jsContext, due.getTime());
```

and that works, **but**... it results in a *Cannot serialize JavaScript function* error when the object is to be serialized.

Comment: Try oo.put("DoB", FBSUtility.wrap( new Date().getTime() )). Inspiration: https://github.com/egmar/xpages-logreader/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/src/com/debug/DebugToolbar.java

Comment: Thanks, I saw that too. Problem is, getTime() returns a long, but I'd really like a Date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to ditch JSContext, ObjectObject and ArrayObject objects altogether, and use one of the other JSON classes available. I started using these two:

```
import com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaArray;
import com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaObject;
```

An additional advantage is that one can forget all about the FBSUtility wrap thing.